# How escrow works on software projects?

Tags: requirements, freelancing, contract

My *understanding* of escrow, as it is used in software projects between a "**client**" (commissioning the software/app) and a "**contractor**" (developer; provider of application services) is as follows:

- The client & contractor sign some type of Master Service Agreement (MSA) and 1+ Statements of Work (SoW), which identifies how much the client will pay for the software system; let's keep it simple and say this amount is $10
- The client creates an account with a designated **escrow service**, and places $10 in that account
- The contractor can now verify (through the escrow service) that the $10 is located in the account. The contractor builds the software
- The contractor delivers the software to the client and notifies the escrow service
- The escrow service has an arbitrator that independently verifies whether the delivered system meets the requirements identified in the MSA/SoW

  - If the software *does* meet these requirements, the escrow service pays the contractor
  - Else, the terms of the contract dictate what happens

**Is my understanding of escrow/escrow services, and their typical use in software contracts, correct or am I misled horribly?**

Comment: If it's ever used, this could be one way, but in many projects, there's a percentage paid upfront and many businesses don't want to tie up too much cash during a lengthy project. If you're going to this much trouble, it's probably a lengthy project. Usually, they send an invoice and go to court for nonpayment.

Comment: Your question is being discussed [here](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/8036/1204).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about traditional forms of [financial escrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escrow) and not about considerations related to software [source code escrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_escrow).

Comment: Well @ThomasOwens, for the record I categorically (but respectfully!) disagree. However there's nothing I can do; your decision is made. But at least this question will stay "public + searchable" and hopefully can prove useful to freelancers in the future.

Comment: @smeeb If you disagree, feel free to participate in the [discussion on Meta](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/8036/1204). But you will need to explain how your question pertains to [source code escrow, as defined on WIkipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_escrow) and fits [our definition of what is on-topic](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), keeping in mind that we are software developers and not lawyers or experts in contracts. If this question should be reopened, I'd be happy to look into it further. I just don't see how it fits into our scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's one way to do it.  Finding and paying a qualified arbitrator to determine that the delivered system meets the requirements of the MSA/SoW can be a problem.  Furthermore, it's not unusual for requirements to change during the development process.

I've seen escrow services used more often in the context of "contractor regularly deposits source code in the repository and if the contractor goes out of business then the client gets a copy of the code".

"Did the contractor go out of business?" is a much easier question to answer than "does the code meet the requirements?"

As for protecting the parties, I've had success using a "mini escrow".  I would ask the client to pay me 60 days in advance.  I would provide weekly reports showing progress both in terms of hours and deliverables (code changes).  I would deliver source code to the client as soon as possible.  When I'd used up the 60 days of pay, the client could choose to pay another 60 days or not.  By the time we reached the end of the contract (where finishing up was less than 60 days) we had enough trust in each other that the last tasks were completed on a handshake.

The client risks 60 days of contractor pay (but no more).  The contractor knows he will be paid for the work that he has promised to do.  Both sides have the ability to leave if things don't work out.

Comment: This is the kind I've hear of before.

Comment: Thanks @Dan Pichelman (+1) - Can you please see my question underneath Encaitar's answer - I have the same question for you! Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

I have seen a different meaning to the term escrow as it relates to software development and contracting.

- Developer stores encrypted version of the software's source code with
  an escrow service.
- Escrow service periodically tries to contact the developer /
  contracting company to see if they are still alive / in business and
  servicing the software product.
- If after a designated number of attempts / time the escrow service
  can not raise the developer then the software is considered
  unsupported and the software source code is transferred to the
  client.

Obviously this is a big deal for the developer as they are potentially giving a lot away. However if the client is basing their business on the software and are worried about these scenarios and if they pay enough money then it can be deemed worth it.

This does not protect the developer from not being paid (I'd suggest getting some of the fee upfront), and doesn't protect the client from getting what they want. I believe that is a much bigger question, maybe ask it as a separate question on here.

Comment: Thanks @Encaitar (+1) - it is strange to me that: (1) there's nothing (escrow-related) that protects the contractor against nonpayment, and (2) there's nothing (again, escrow-related) that protects the client for software that fails to meet requirements. It seems that both of those cases are handled in court? **Can you please confirm?** Thanks again!

Comment: Also, **very important**, wouldn't the client *already* be entitled to the source code since they were the ones that paid for it in the first place?

Comment: @smeeb Quick A to other Q: I would suggest an Agile approach where you continually work with the client to refine the stories. A single set of requirements approved upfront is not what you are working towards, it will change over time and the most important thing is to get a happy customer. The word 'requirements' suggests an immutable set that must be met at all costs but that almost always seems to end in disappointment, if the customer could enumerate exactly what they wanted to the level required by a computer program upfront then you can implement the DSL in Lisp and be done.

Comment: @smeeb The client would be entitled to the source code if they had agreed that in the contract. Some people do that, others keep the IP with the developer so they can build on it in their next project.

Comment: This answer is my understanding of source code escrow, as well. If you look at the [Wikipedia page for non-functional requirement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_requirement) linked to in revision 1 of the question, the link for "escrow" goes to the [Wikipedia page for source code escrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_escrow). What is described in the question is indeed escrow, but I would not expect to find that information as a software requirement. I would expect the requirements to include what Wikipedia calls source code escrow, which aligns with this answer.